# Access generated properties with unknown property names in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Using the following generated array example structure, how can I loop through and extract the property names and their associated values from each object?

```
[{"bg_2":"0.50"},{"bg_7":"0.10"},{"bg_12":"0.20"}]
```

The number of objects may change, and the property names will not be consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the key, then use the key to get the value.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0fLgvz7/)

```js
var myData = [{"bg_2":"0.50"},{"bg_7":"0.10"},{"bg_12":"0.20"}];

for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    var myObject = myData[i];
    var firstKey = Object.keys(myObject)[0];
    var value = myObject[firstKey];

    console.log(firstKey + ": " + value);
}
```

See also: [ECMAScript® Language Specification: 15.2.3.14 Object.keys ( O )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14)

Comment: Thanks so much. I was going in circles on this and your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on [@AR7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3772221/ar7)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012843/4639281), in the case that there may be multiple properties in each of the objects you can cache the object returned by `Object.keys()` and loop through each property within the array loop.

Using the method below, you can handle any number of properties within the object.

I realize this may not be any more useful in this specific situation than the aforementioned answer, but hopefully it will be useful to future viewers.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1eo6kczw/)

```js
var a = [
    { "bg_2":"0.50", "bg_7":"0.10", "bg_12":"0.20"},
    { "bg_2":"0.50", "bg_7":"0.10"},
    { "bg_2":"0.50"}
];

a.forEach(function(o){
    console.log(o);
    var k = Object.keys(o);
    for(var i in k)
        console.log(k[i], ':', o[k[i]]);
});
```